# pdo show data from 3 tables

Tags: database, pdo

I want to make a script form my database that display the follow data:

Day 1:
Travel: The Heage - Rotterdam
Sleeping: Sky Hostel

Day 2:
Sleeping: Sky Hostel
Activity: visiting Euromast

Day 3:
Travel: Rotterdam - Utrecht
Sleeping: Dom Hostel

i have the follow database:

1. travel

   - day
   - beginlocation
   - destiny
2. sleeping

   - day
   - hostel
3. activity

   - day
   - activity

Answer (score 0):

Here is the SQL you will to get data from all three tables:

```
SELECT travel.day, 
       travel.beginlocation, 
       travel.destiny, 
       sleeping.hostel,
       activity.activity
FROM travel 
    INNER JOIN sleeping 
        ON day = sleeping.day
    INNER JOIN images
        ON day = activity.day
```